# Can I use j-cloth to squeeze water out of grated zucchini?

Tags: equipment, vegetables

As per title.

Can I use [j-cloth](https://www.jcloth.com/) to squeeze water out of grated zucchini ?

I will be using never used/new j-cloth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could*, but it shouldn't be your first choice.  J-cloths are too porous and not nearly strong enough when wet; they are likely to tear spill the zucchini all over the counter while squeezing.  You'd have to treat it very carefully to not stress it too much.

A plain cotton, linen, muslin, or blend cloth is going to work much better.  I use a cotton flour sack towel, which can then be washed.  If you don't have those, putting the shredded zucchini between triple layers of paper towel is still a better bet than a single j-cloth.  You could, conceivably, layer the zucchini between multiple layers of j-cloth, using 4-6 of them.